# msp430-uart-receiving big data

Tags: uart, msp430, receiver

I want to take data from sensor with UART. But I know the coming data from uart like;

decimal =  126 0 10 131 0 0 27 0 1 2 0 - - 159

hexadecimal = 7E 00 0A 83 00 00 24 00 01 02 00 01 7A DA

Firstly, I want to learn that can I take that long data ? and  I want to learn that how can I save data come from UCA0RXBUF?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are really asking what to do with a stream of data bytes.

In a small system, the best way to handle a byte stream is usually one byte at a time.  Since the meaning of some bytes depend on the values of previous bytes, the byte stream is usually decoded in a state machine.

I like to use a separate task for decoding asynchronous byte streams.  You can think of that as a state machine where the PC is the state variable.

Exactly how to decode the byte stream depends on the protocol.  You may need to know where packet boundaries are by some out-of-band means, or by just staying in sync.  There are too many possible protocols to go into different ones here.  Without a description of your particular protocol, there is little more to say here.

Comment: Of course I want to ask that stream of data bytes. I want to learn that how can I take all data that stream until 14 bytes, what is the useful way or codes to get all bytes?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit what you actually wanna do with this data. The buffer has a defined size and is filled by the UART whenever data is received. What you listed above I wouldn't consider big data, just create a routine that fills e.g. an Array or whatever serves your needs.
For such cases it's also very helpful to check the examples you get with most board support packages for your chip.